# Importance of used generator building libraries on windows

Tags: visual-studio, qt, build

World was easy using U-buntu building up my environment consisting of Qt,Qt-Creator,ITK,VTK,openCV and PCL. Download source-code and install missing dependencies via apt-get or build them also from source using make. Now on windows things are different. I installed VS2022 and started building VTK, PCL, openCV generating a VS .sln and I started being euphoric. But building Qt and Qt-Creator make me headaches. Qt recommends using ninja, which also come with VS.
My target is to use Qt-Creator with CMake to combine Qt,VTK,PCL and so on.

What impact does the chosen generator have later on regarding compatibility? Can I mix a VS .sln build with a nmake/ninja build later on?

Is a ninja build also a MSVC build?

Comment: ***Can I mix a VS .sln build with a nmake/ninja build later on?*** Yes, you can mix binaries produced using ninja with msvc as the compiler and Visual Studio project files.

Comment: You may want to look into `vcpkg` as it automates the building of dependencies for you.  Qt, PCL, VTK are all in vcpkg.